# How to pass Googleapiclient to another all activity for Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-api-client, leaderboard

I have tried using many documents and resources but I can't find a correct way to pass Googleapiclient to another activity.
For me **Google play games sign in successful** is in one activity. I want to submit score in another activity.
Please give an idea on how to complete my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be constantly connected to the GoogleApiClient then I would probably make a singleton class to handle GoogleApiClient calls.

```
/**
 *  Class to maintain singlton object of google api
 */
public class GoogleApiClient_Singleton {
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleApiClient";
    private static GoogleApiClient_Singleton instance = null;

    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;

    protected GoogleApiClient_Singleton() {

    }

    public static GoogleApiClient_Singleton getInstance(GoogleApiClient aGoogleApiClient) {

        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new GoogleApiClient_Singleton();

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
                mGoogleApiClient = aGoogleApiClient;
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient get_GoogleApiClient(){
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

Or For accessing object from every where,

create object in Application class file. Don't forget to add app in manifest.
Then create a new instance of the GoogleApiClient in my second activity and then get the api client like this

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static App mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public void setClient(GoogleApiClient client){
        mGoogleApiClient = client;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getClient(){
       return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}

// In second activity
GoogleApiClient client = App.getInstance().getClient();
```

**Update In Manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    ... other tags
    />
```

Comment: I added App.java like second answer, and i will put this method GoogleApiClient client=App.getInstance().getClient() in another activity; but it shows red underline with cannot resolve or create Getter or create Property. Whether i need to create Application.java and how to put App.java in AndroidManifestfile

Comment: please reply pannunga sir

Comment: please reply for this

Comment: @KrishnakumarR Check my updated answer and still u have problem then add some code so i can check. and if answer is helpful accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I am solved that error by providing sign in code in all of the activity.
so that i solved sign in one activity and submit score another activity error was solved.
**Google Play Games** sign in was implemented by using below link.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin